# React, my button in each row is only deleting the last element when I click on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const {useState} = React;
function Row({ id, delete1 }) {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
  function checkmark() {
    console.log("checkmark clicked");
    setCheck(!check);
  }

  let message;
  let even;
  if (check) {
    message = "task completed";
  } else {
    message = "task not completed";
  }
  if (id % 2 === 0) {
    even = "even";
  } else {
    even = "odd";
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input type='checkbox' onClick={checkmark}></input>
      <input type='text'></input>
      <button onClick={() => delete1(id)}>Delete Task</button>
      {message}
      {even}
    </div>
  );
}

function Display({ inputs, delete1 }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {inputs.map((value, index) => {
        return <Row key={index} id={index} delete1={delete1} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
  function addRow() {
    setArr((arr) => [...arr, {}]);
  }
  function delete_arr(id) {
    const newArr = arr.filter((_, index) => index !== id);
    setArr(newArr);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <header>TO DO LIST</header>
      <Display inputs={arr} delete1={delete_arr} />
      <button onClick={addRow}>Add New Task</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Whenever I click on any of the delete tasks, it only deletes the last task. I've tried looking at the id's and they print the correct result, but I'm not sure why it's only deleting. In my delete arr, I'm only deleting the element that is equal to id. So if my id printing the correct id when I click "delete task", I am not sure why its not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a demonstration of this? The code looks OK to me, but I'm wondering if you're expecting, if you click to delete say an "odd" row, for there to then be 2 "even"s displayed next to each other? That won't happen because you're always passing the indexes of the current `arr` state in as the IDs, which update as items are added and deleted from the array.

Comment: `key={index}` this is where things go wrong. you are using the index as key. Now when removing an element somewhere inside the array all keys stay the same except for the very last item no matter which element you remove. React only looks at the key here and just sees that the key of the very last element changed/is missing so it removes that item from the dom and not the actual removed one. To fix this you need to use an unique value for each row that doesnt change when removing other items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whenever I click on any of the delete tasks, it only deletes the last task.

If you are mutating, sorting, filtering the `data` array, you **cannot**, or at least **you shouldn't** use `index` as a *key*. In your particular case, when deleting a row, elements get shifted because of the conflict with `keys` (`index` keys are not static).

When replaced with `static` keys, it works correctly.

```
function addRow() {
  setArr((arr) => [...arr, { id: uuid() }]); // assign a static key
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-chatterjee-2qkrd2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
const newArr = arr.filter((item, index) => item?.id !== id);
```

**item?.id** instead of index.